# For loop to append all numbers to variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote some code to open a text file and take the columns that I need and assign it to a variable. Everything before the `for` loop is OK. Now inside the loop, I want to have all numbers in `g` as a list of doubles, but all the time I have only last number of `lis1`.

Thanks in advance.

Codes:

```
import numpy as N
import math as M

with open('File.txt',"r") as f:
    lis1 = [float(line.split()[4]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis2 = [float(line.split()[6]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis3 = [float(line.split()[8]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis4 = [float(line.split()[10]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis5 = [float(line.split()[12]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis6 = [float(line.split()[14]) for line in f]
    i= 0
    j = i+1

    for t in (lis1):
        g = ((lis1[i:j]))                                   
        k = ((lis2[i:j]))                                          
        kl = ((lis3[i:j]))                                    
        kk = ((lis4[i:j]))
        kk2 = ((lis5[i:j]))
        kk3 = ((lis6[i:j]))
        i = i+1
        j = j+1
```

Comment: Interesting that you have the last element. According to your code it should be the first one.

Comment: do you update i, j values in for loop ?

Comment: @zetysz yes. I update them.if I print g(for example), it shows all of them, but assign only last number to g.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: In every iteration of your loop you overwrite your variables. That's why only the last one is kept. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `g` variable is updated in each iteration.

At last if `for t loops 10` you should have `g = ((list1[10:11]))`

***Example:***

```
list1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
i=0  
j=i+1  
for t in list1:  
    g=((list1[i:j]))  
    i+=1  
    j+=1  
...
g = (([9]))
```

We should have to get from the last index to .., which will return the last element.

Comment: maybe I dont understand it. what is the different of this codes and my code.?

Comment: I try to explain the error.To get all your element use for example g.append(list[i:j]).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in each run of the loop you assign `g=lis1[i:j]` which will make `g` end up with the value`lis1[i:j]` have in the loop (which will only be the last element of `lis1`).

If you want `g` to contain all elements of `lis1` you only have to copy `lis1`:

```
import numpy as N
import math as M

with open('File.txt',"r") as f:
    lis1 = [float(line.split()[4]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis2 = [float(line.split()[6]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis3 = [float(line.split()[8]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis4 = [float(line.split()[10]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis5 = [float(line.split()[12]) for line in f]
    f.seek(0)
    lis6 = [float(line.split()[14]) for line in f]

    g = []

    for t in (lis1):
        g.append(t)
```

But then of course one would wonder why you want to do that to begin with (you already have that in `lis1`) - you could do this easier by copying directly as `g=lis1[:]` or even `g=lis1`.

Comment: I am really sorry but I dont understand, what do ou mean with copy lis1?

Comment: Make `g` contain same elements/numbers as `lis1`.

Comment: but here is only little part. I want to Learn it to do it later for all other part of programs. I think I can not use this method for all the programs.

Comment: @kian What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to appent the result of for loop  (that are float numbers) in a list. then I can take out any element with this code:`g[m:n]`.